# Empty element added by default when slice of structs is created with make function

Tags: go, slice

I have a struct defined as shown below :

```
type abc struct {
  srcName string
  destName string
  flag    bool  'default:false'
}
```

In my code , i initialize it with make function

```
var abcList []abc

func init() {
    abcList = make([]abc, 1)
}

func main() {
 var abcElem abc

 abc.srcName = "src"
 abc.destName = "dest"
 abc.flag  = true

 abcList = append(abcList, abc)

 klog.Info("abcList:", abcList)
}
```

I see the output as:

```
abcList: [{    false} {"src", "dest", true}]
```

Want to know why slice element with default value is added.
Isn't it a wrong thing?
If i initialize this slice with bigger capacity, then i see many such elements
with default value.
It adds extra cost while iterating this slice.

Comment: The expression `make([]abc, 1)` creates a slice with a single element set to the zero value. Fix the code by removing the line of code.  The `append` function handles a nil slice argument.  There are many other errors in the code.

Comment: check the go tour https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11 and others SO answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683911/go-slices-capacity-length

Comment: Incidentally this particular mistake—calling `make` with a nonzero initial size when what you had intended is a nonzero initial *capacity* instead—is a common one for those new to Go, used to other languages that require an initial capacity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```golang
make([]abc, 0, 1)
```

The 2nd argument is count for slices, third is the capacity.

If you initialize a slice with `s := make([]abc, 1)` it will contain one empty element. You can overwrite that element with `s[0] = xyz`. If you `append` to the slice, the empty element(s) will stay and new elements will be added.

Note:
The `init` function is not needed here. You can just do:

```golang
// package level declaration
var abcList = make([]abc, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `go  make([]abc, 1)`  has length set to `1`. To understand it, the go syntax for array initialization is

```golang
make([]array, length, capacity)
```

Where a new `array` of size `length` is created and initialized, which can be extended upto `capacity`. In your case `length=1` means, create an array of type `[]abc` and initialize one element with default values. The `capacity` was not present which means `capacity=n`

You can avoid the default value initialization by,

```golang
make([]abc, 0, <1...n>)
```

or

```golang
abcList = []abc{}
```

Answer (score 0):

make([]abc, 0, 1) or just use only var abcList []abc don't initilize with make

Answer (score -1):

I don't see where the init code is called. The above code something you must have missed when posting this question. You are not invoking `init()` anywhere in `main()`

The init function is unncessary since you are using append in the main() function.

Comment: `init` functions of all packages are called by Go before the `main` function is called.

Comment: I never used init, glad to know. I will update my answer.

Comment: It is actually considered bad practice to use init as it is usually used for global state.